# Create and open file with javascript not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

I have the following code:

```
var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' });

var downloadLink = angular.element('<a></a>');
downloadLink.attr('href', window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));

downloadLink.attr('download', test.txt);
downloadLink[0].click();
```

I'm creating a file and opening it on the browser. This work fine in Chrome but it doesn't work in Firefox.

I don't receive any errors.

What am I missed?

Comment: Consider using this example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/koldev/cW7W5/)

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox, add:

```
document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
```

right before the click() call.

(And optionally `document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);` at the end)

Comment: Thanks but this makes no difference